# scala + kafka does not send message with id

Tags: scala, akka, apache-kafka

I'm trying to send a message to Kafka through my actor and it does not work.

The following code works

```
new KeyedMessage[String, Array[Byte]]("my-topic", msg.message)
```

This one doesn't... why?

```
new KeyedMessage[String, Array[Byte]]("my-topic", msg.id, msg.message)
```

or even

```
new KeyedMessage[String, Array[Byte]]("my-topic", msg.id, null, msg.message)
```

setting partition to null, forcing it to fill only the id, but still the same.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Well, just realize it does not work when sending message as byte array.

I've changed my code to allow sending message as string and it works.

With the following it does not work:

```
  props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder")

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: Message =>
      val keyedMessage = new KeyedMessage[String, Array[Byte]]("my-topic", msg.id, msg.message)
      producer.send(keyedMessage)

    case _ => log.error("Got a msg that I don't understand")
  }
```

Modifying the Array[Byte] to String along with the DefaultEncoder to StringEncoder, it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just found out the problem.

Actually you have two options for Encoder. The DefaultEncoder and the StringEncoder. I was trying to send my id as String and the message as byte array using the default encoder.

Looking at the Encoder.scala, you can see the DefaultEncoder implementation and the answer.

```
/**
 * The default implementation is a no-op, it just returns the same array it takes in
 */
class DefaultEncoder(props: VerifiableProperties = null) extends Encoder[Array[Byte]] {
  override def toBytes(value: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = value
}
```

It just returns the byte array, and since I was passing a String, it was throwing cast exception.